# How can I open an MP3 with quicktime player using applescript?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

I have the following code to open the files, but they all open with iTunes:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the_files to get every file of folder ("Macintosh 
    SSD:Users:myusername:Desktop:DJ:Music:Sort")
end tell

repeat with theItem in the_files
    tell application "QuickTime Player"
        open theItem
    end tell
end repeat
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AS syntax can be very misleading. While your `open` command is inside a `tell application … end tell` block, that doesn’t necessarily mean it will be sent to that application. If the command’s direct parameter happens to be a reference to objects in another app (in this case, a reference to a `document file` object in Finder) AS will send it to *that* app instead.

Use `set the_files to get every file of folder (…) as alias list`. That will get you a list of AppleScript `alias` values, instead of a list of Finder references (which any app other than Finder wouldn’t understand anyway).